# Prevent queued events from being executed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a handler which is triggered for two events:

1. blur trigger of object A.
2. click on object B.

The problem is when Object A has focus and I click on B, both the events are triggered. I want to stop this from happening. The handler should be executed only once in this case because there's a `toggle()` inside which is being nullified due to the second call. Is there any way I can clear all pending events on an object?

```
<div id='panel'>Hey!</div>    

<input type='text' id='a'>
<div id='b'>Hello</div>
```

---

```
function handler() {
    $('#panel').toggle();
}

$('#a').blur(handler);
$('#b').click(handler);
```

When the textbox has the focus **and** the user clicks on the div 'b', two events are triggered - *blur* of input *a* and *click* of div *b*. Both the events are handled by the same function and since the function incidentally toggles another element *(panel)*, the functionality fails since the two toggles cancel each other out. So, what I need is a a way to clear out all pending events for an element.

Comment: The easiest way is to return false from those functions.But,of course, it will depend on what you have written.

Comment: @Kai - `return false` would only stop the *current* event type :) @manu - can you post your code? It'd be much easier to provide a solution by seeing what you currently have.

Comment: Returning false won't work because the events are not propagated. They're two completely different events which happen to fire simultaneously.

Comment: @akula1001 did you ever figure this out? i'm in a situation where a ton of scroll events get queued in a short period of time, and i need to single out the first event and remove the remaining ones.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Or, maybe you need to [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) one event, then rebind it after the other event has fired.

[`.undelegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) may do what you're after:

> Remove a handler from the event for all elements which match the current selector, 
>   now or in the future, based upon a specific set of root elements.

Comment: I tried unbind() followed by bind() (to reattach the triggers) but the second event still fires because it has already been triggered. Looks like both the events are put on a queue and unbind() doesn't cause already triggered events to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in the event handler.</strike>

> ***Description***:  Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

---

What if you keep track of the events firing, and block the toggle from being called if the other has already been called?

```
var called = false;

function handler() {
   if (!called) {
      called = true;
      $('#panel').toggle(1, function () { // change the duration to your liking
          called = false;
      });
   }
}

$('#a').blur(handler);
$('#b').click(handler);
```

Haven't tested yet, but I believe this should work.

EDIT: It worked fine, but then again, when I tested the original handler I did not get the behavior you said you were getting -- the handler was only called once, even in the situation you described (focused input, click on "b"). I tested it in FF 3.6, IE8, and Chrome 5.

Comment: Yes, looks like this is the function but it does not work. I wonder if this is because the two events are of different type or because the events are on different elements. Just the handler for both the events are same. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: @manu1001: Oops, I thought you said the events were fired from the same element. There's no reason it should work with two different elements. In fact, I'm not 100% sure it would work with different events on the same element. I think I have a solution though, I'll edit it into my answer.